# Let Statement/Random Function in Scheme

Tags: random, scheme, distance, formula

I was wondering if I would be able to use the built in let function from scheme to define two random variables within the function without their values changing throughout the code. For example if I wrote:

```
 (let (x (- (* 2 (random)) 1)))
 (let (y (- (* 2 (random)) 1)))
```

Would the value of x be constant until the function exits? I want to square x and y and take the square root of them, but I need their values to remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `let` binds a value to the given identifier, and its value doesn't change unless you use `set!` on it.

So you can do this:

```
(let ((x (- (* 2 (random)) 1))
      (y (- (* 2 (random)) 1)))
  (sqrt (+ (* x x) (* y y))))
```

Of course, I find it easier to define a `hypot` function for what you're doing (corresponding to C's [`hypot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot) function):

```
(define (hypot x y)
  (sqrt (+ (* x x) (* y y))))

(hypot (- (* 2 (random)) 1)
       (- (* 2 (random)) 1))
```

Now you don't need to use `let` at all!

In case the connection isn't immediately obvious, the way `let` works behind the scenes is to create a function (with pretty much the same contents as `hypot`, in this case), and just calls that function with the values you're binding. So, the two snippets of code above are effectively identical (except that the latter one also adds a top-level binding for `hypot`).